# Redimensionar Gráfico Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, chartjs

Estou usando [Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) e tenho um [gráfico radar](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#radar-chart).

Veja o código abaixo: Também tenho [esse fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jedarc/y4trpr15/3/).

```js
var radarChartData = {
  labels: ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"],
    
    datasets: [
   {
    label: "Linha1",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [2,2,2,2]
   },
   {
    label: "Linha2",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [8,8,8,8]
   }
  ]
 };

 window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData, {
            responsive: true,
        //scaleShowLabels : true,
        animationSteps: 80,
        animationEasing: "easeOutQuart",
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 10,
        scaleStepWidth: 1,
        scaleStartValue: 0,
        angleShowLineOut : false,
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
        
        legendTemplate : '<% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) { %>'
                    +'<h3 style=\"color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\">.'
                    +'<% if (datasets[i].label) { %><%= datasets[i].label %><% }%>'
                +'<% } %></h3>',
        
        //Number - Pixel width of the angle line
    angleLineWidth : 100,

    //String - Point label font declaration
    pointLabelFontFamily : "Arial",

    //String - Point label font weight
    pointLabelFontStyle : "normal",

    //Number - Point label font size in pixels
    pointLabelFontSize : 20,

    //String - Point label font colour
    pointLabelFontColor : "black",
         // String - Template string for single tooltips
            tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label %>: <%}%><%= value %>",
            // String - Template string for multiple tooltips
            multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> : <%= value %>",
        });

document.getElementById("legendDiv").innerHTML = window.myRadar.generateLegend();
```

```css
#canvas-container {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    canvas {
        display: inline;
        background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-container">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
<div id="legendDiv"></div>
```

A questão é que eu gostaria que o gráfico aproveitasse todo o espaço na horizontal, mas não consigo alterar o `width`.

O que tenho é isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu gostaria era desse resultado (se possível sem perder a qualidade, já que estamos falando em canvas):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]


`responsive: true` não tem resolvido meu problema.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Tenta usar o versao 2.0-alpha3 em "Releases". Contem "samples" tambem.

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer é usar os métodos de transformação do canvas pra esticar o gráfico, mas ai você perde os eventos de mouse do gráfico(ficam "tortos")

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.translate(-canvas.width*0.5, 0);
ctx.scale(canvas.width / (myRadar.scale.size), 1);
```